# How to generate auto increment temporary field in MySQL with join and order by clause

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Here is my poeples tables

```
+----+------------------+------------+
| id | name             | address    |
+----+------------------+------------+
|  1 | Tony Stark       | Chicago    |
|  2 | Natasha Romanoff | Boston     |
|  3 | Steve Rogers     | Arkansas   |
|  4 | Bruce Banner     | Long Beach |
+----+------------------+------------+
```

Here is my roles table

```
+----+-----------------+-----------+
| id | role_name       | people_id |
+----+-----------------+-----------+
|  1 | Iron Man        |         1 |
|  2 | Black Widow     |         2 |
|  3 | Captain America |         3 |
|  4 | Hulk            |         4 |
+----+-----------------+-----------+
```

I want to get the data from that 2 tables with generate auto increment sequential number field with this query

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 as no, peoples.name, roles.role_name
FROM peoples
CROSS JOIN (select @rownum := 0) r
JOIN roles ON roles.people_id = peoples.id
ORDER BY peoples.name ASC
```

But the result is not what i expect. Here is the result

```
+------+------------------+-----------------+
| no   | name             | role_name       |
+------+------------------+-----------------+
|    4 | Bruce Banner     | Hulk            |
|    2 | Natasha Romanoff | Black Widow     |
|    3 | Steve Rogers     | Captain America |
|    1 | Tony Stark       | Iron Man        |
+------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Maybe it's because of the JOIN and ORDER BY. How to fix that so i get a sequential number?

Comment: Given that no one has multiple roles and no role has multiple people, why have a separate table at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a row number by name over the `peoples` table, you should first generate it in a subquery, and then join to that subquery:

```
SELECT
    p.no,
    p.name,
    r.role_name
FROM
(
    SELECT id, name, address, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS no
    FROM peoples
    ORDER BY name
) p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) t
INNER JOIN roles r
    ON p.id = r.people_id
ORDER BY
    p.no;
```

Comment: What if i want to order by role_name?

Comment: Then you would subquery on `roles` and compute the row number there.  It should be easy enough to adapt my answer to do this.